# How to prevent MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter from taking over serialization?

Tags: spring, jackson, resttemplate

I'm using `RestTemplate` to interact with several REST services, some of them accept/return JSON and some XML. To that end, I've added [Jackson's dataformat-xml module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) as a dependency (along with the [JAXB annotations module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations)). `RestTemplate` automatically includes `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`  (done in the `RestTemplate` constructor).

This creates a situation where some objects that are used as the `request` parameter in calls to

```
RestTemplate.postForObject(String url, Object request, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)`
```

get serlialized as XML and the content-type of the request is set to `application/xml`. For example:

```
MyObject request = ...;
String url = ...;
MyResponseObject response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, MyResponseObject.class);
```

`RestTemplate` tries to serialize `MyObject` to XML and sets the request media type to `application/xml`.

Problem is, many of the services we call don't accept XML (they expect JSON). So now that I have `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` on the classpath, it's taking precedence over the JSON converter which makes the calls to JSON services fail.

I suppose I could change my calling code to pass an `HttpEntity` with the media type explicitly set to JSON instead of my simple data object, but that's kind of ugly (boilerplate) and would mean changing quite a few service calling code.

Is there a way to either

A) change the priority of the MessageConverters so that the standard Jackons (JSON) one takes priority over `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`

or

B) Prevent `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` from claiming that it can serialize the objects I don't want it to

?

Comment: set the variable as `transient`?

Comment: what version of Spring?  Have you tried configuring a `ContentNegotiationManager` or `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` with the priority you want?

Comment: @Rodrigo, it's not a member that is being incorrectly serialized, it's the entire objet.

Comment: Ok but java allows you declare a object as `transient`, thus that object will not be serialised.

Comment: @BrianKent: Isn't that for Spring MVC and *providing* a REST service (as opposed to *consuming*)? I didn't think content negotiation comes into play for REST calls via `RestTemplate`...

Comment: @E-Riz: yes, you are totally right! I was thinking they used the same machinery, but they definitely do not. Sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two options :

- Create a `RestTemplate` with the HttpMessageConverter you want, in the order you want them to be used (check `HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest` they are used in the order they are in the list and the first *matching* converter will be used
- As you suggested, using an `HttpEntity` and setting the `Content-Type` header to the mime type you want to get.

I think using a helper to create an `HttpEntity` with your object and the correct Content-Type header would be safer :

```
public class HttpEntityHelper {

    public static <T> HttpEntity<T> jsonHttpEntity(T body) {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        return new HttpEntity(body, headers);
    }
}
```